# Using Graphics from my Frame's paint() gives cutting effect every call to repaint()

Tags: java, graphics, rendering

Every frame the run() method of my thread calls the repaint() of the frame subclass, in this frame subclass I override the paint(Graphics) and since I want to have different screens from my game I pass the Graphics g parameter to an instance of the PlayScreen class where I do my drawing for that particular screen. The issue comes whenever the run() calls repaint() and the tile start to flash rendered on and off. I am starting to suspect that the issue comes from the order in which I set my repaint() and draw() calls.
[image: Picture of effect]

GameObject(class with run method).

```
@Override
public void run() {
    isAlive = true;
 try{
     while(isAlive){
     Thread.sleep(17);
    screen.repaint();
     }
 }catch(Exception x){

 }

}
```

Screen class that extends Frame

```
@Override
public void paint(Graphics g) {
    playScreen.draw(g);

}
```

PlayScreen(where the tiles are rendered)

```
public void draw(Graphics g){
    for(ArrayList<Tile> tileArray: tiles){
        for(Tile tile : tileArray){
            g.drawImage(tile.getTile(), tile.getX(), tile.getY(), null);
        }
    }

}
```

Comment: What happens if you change the number 17 to something larger?

Comment: I suggest you paint on a subclass of JComponet.

Comment: have you tried to use custom rendering instead? as it seems you don't need any components but merely graphics?